# Different og:description for facebook send button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have got facebook like, share and send buttons. I have filled the og:tags correctly but now I've got a problem: I want a different og:description for my send button, is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: No. Only if you send a different url

Comment: really? and what about FB.ui() ? Can I somehow use it?